# Authorization issue with NetCDF Java

Tags: java, netcdf, unidata, opendap, netcdf-java

I am trying to get data from a password restricted server with netcdf-java. I have set up an RC based authentication as [described in the unidata docs](https://docs.unidata.ucar.edu/netcdf-c/4.8.1/md_auth.html). I have the env variable `DAPRCFILE` pointing to `/some/daprc/location/.daprc`, in which I have `HTTP.NETRC=/some/other/location/.netrc`, of which the content is

```
machine mmmmmm 
login xxxxxx 
password yyyyyy
```

However, whenever I try to get data with `NetcdfDatasets.openFile(...)` I am getting an `Authorization failure` response. I have tried with `nccopy`/`ncdump` which indeed does work. So either netcdf-java does not pick up on the rc file config, or there are some nuances that I may have missed. I've tried setting up an `HTTPSession` with a custom `HTTPCredentialsProvider`, but couldn't get it working. I've also tried url based authentication, but could not get it working with `ncdump`/`nccopy` either.

How do I get authentication working with netcdf-java?

Comment: What sort of error/failure are you getting? I have a custom CredentialsProvider subclass that because the app may be accessing different servers, when called, the provider invokes a UI password dialog to get the user's credentials.